# Bottom Border on Bootstrap Row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a heading for a section of a page using Bootstrap's grid system, like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        Heading Text
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">
        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is add a rule - a horizontal line - below the heading row, so that it looks like this (this uses different icons, but don't worry about that):
[image: Example]

I can achieve this perfectly by adding this code before the closing tag of the `div` with the `.row` class:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div style='border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;'></div>
</div>
```

However, this seems cumbersome to add in all over the place, even if I move the styling to the stylesheet. I've obviously been able to achieve the same effect using `append` in jQuery (though that has caused issues of its own), but what I'd really like is to accomplish this using pure CSS.

Ideally, I'd add a class to the `div` with the `.row` class and the adding of the line would be handled by CSS in the style sheet, but I can't figure it out. The main obstacle is that the child `divs` to the row have padding of 15px left and right, so if I add the bottom border to the parent row `div`, the line extends beyond the header content at either end.

Is there a way I can accomplish what I want using pure CSS?

Comment: why not assigning the `border-bottom` to the `.row`??

Comment: @FarzadYZ _"The main obstacle is that the child divs to the row have padding of 15px left and right, so if I add the bottom border to the parent row div, the line extends beyond the header content at either end."_

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could do this with a pseudo element with left and right margin to overcome the padding issue:

```css
@import "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css";

.row-bordered:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-bordered">
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      Heading Text
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 text-right">
      <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
      <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I was close to this solution, but I was trying to put HTML into the `Content` property of the class, which I know doesn't work. I didn't know I could create a pseudo-element in this way, thanks for introducing me to the concept!

Comment: just curious, this works great for getting a bottom border flush with a .row without worry of the negative margins caused by .row itself. Is there a way to do this for get a border-top flush on a .row (so to setup a border at the top of a .row section so it matches the perfect border-bottom your code fixes)?  was hoping this would work, but doesn't seem to:     .row:before{ border-top: 1px solid #CCC; }

Comment: Using `:before` works fine for me. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/5p6o8e4f/

Comment: Needed `width: 100%` for me, would make a great SASS mixin

Answer (score 6):

The solution above longer works in Bootstrap 4 due to switching to Flexbox, but a few modifications fixes it:

```css
.row-bordered {
  position: relative;
}

.row-bordered:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row row-bordered">
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    Heading Text
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">
    <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
    <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine for me. But the class call in the HTML should be '.row-bordered' and not 'row-border'.